# How to split static ip into 2 ip's to be sent to two local ip's?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

I need to split static IP into 2 ports to be sent for two systems.

I have two systems having local IP address `192.169.0.1` and `192.168.0.5` and my static IP is `202.63.90.24`. When I ping from outside network using static IP it is going to `192.168.0.1` and not to `192.x.x.5`. How can I split static IP into two, so that I can ping using different static IP like `202.63.90.24/1` or `2`? Is it possible to split it into two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should make some terms clear:

- Your local IP addresses are **private addresses** which cannot be used on the Internet because they are not unique there and cannot be unambiguously routed in the scope of the whole Internet.
- Your static IP address `202.63.90.24` is your **public IP address** (unique in the Internet) which was statically assigned to you probably by your ISP.
- To be able to access services on the systems with private IP addresses from the Internet you must somehow translate your public IP address to the private IP address of your destination system. This mechanism is called **network address translation** (**NAT**).
- To be able to differentiate different services running on a single system we are using **port numbers**. For example HTTP (web server) usually listens on port 80.

In your case you are translating all traffic going to `202.63.90.24` to the private address `192.168.0.1`. The other private IP address cannot be directly accessed from the Internet. The translation is performed on the router between your private network and your internet connection.

To be able to access services on both the systems with private addresses you can include port numbers into the NAT rules to differentiate between the services and consequently the destination systems. So for example you can translate `202.63.90.24:80 -> 192.168.0.1:80` and `202.63.90.24:22 -> 192.168.0.5:22`. In other words: When you access port `80` (HTTP) on your public IP address it will be directed to your system `192.168.0.1`, when you access the port `22` (SSH) it will be directed to `192.168.0.5`.

Comment: How to configure NAT on DLink dir 600m router.

Comment: In my case Incomming Ports are same 3200. How Can i configure..

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know this specific router. Please try to configure the NAT yourself - now you know the basic theory. If you come to a point where you do not know how to continue, consult the documentation and information on the Internet. If you still cannot continue, ask a new question for your specific problem here.

Comment: Regarding the same ports: In such a case you can translate also the port number. For example: `202.63.90.24:3200 -> 192.168.0.1:3200` and `202.63.90.24:3201 -> 192.168.0.5:3200`. If the application is not able to communicate to a different port (`3201`) then things are more complicated and you can use for example some kind of tunnelling (e.g. a VPN) which is considerably more complicated than NAT. Good luck :)